# Django url pattern issue in python 2.7.6

Tags: python, html, django

I searched a lot about my problem but couldn't find a solution probably because I am not good at looking or understanding. But I am searching about this for 2 days but couldn't find something that solves it.

I am working on a project with django.When I run the website I get no error. but when I click the buttons (home page and contact stuff), `http://127.0.0.1:8000/first/first/first/first/iletisim.html` it makes something like this. everytime I click iletisim button (its in turkish contact in english) it adds /first itself and nothing changes on the webpage it stays still on the homepage.

Edited : another issue is I also can't log in as admin. İf go in to /admin it redirects me to home page...

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG7qw.jpg)

I only made contact blog and homepage until this point. I will try to put folder orders in here so mybe you guys will have an idea about the later.

haliyikama/haliyikama/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'first',
'blog',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

haliyikama/haliyikama/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('first.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

haliyikama/first/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^home', views.index, name = 'home'),
    url(r'^first/iletisim', views.contact, name = 'iletisim')
]

haliyikama/first/views.py


from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'first/home.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request,'first/iletisim.html', {'content':['Eger bizimle iletisime gecmek isterseniz mail adresimizi kullanabilirsiniz.', 'gulumhali@outlook.com']})
```

When I try to put $ sign in the my-site urls.py file at first place it does not open anypage it gaves 404 error indicates that I shouldn't put $ but if I don't put that I am stuck in home page.

These are the html files if you guys need to solve my problem;

These are in haliyikama/first/templates/first

iletisim.html

```
{% extends "first/header.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% for c in content %}
        <p>{{c}}</p>

    {%endfor%}

{% endblock %}
```

home.html

```
{% extends "first/header.html" %}
{% block content %}


<div class = "hero-unit">
    <div class="container">

        <h2 class="text-center">Gülüm Halı Yıkama Servisi</h2>
        <p  class="text-center">Kaliteli hizmetin adresi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="Gülüm-Halı-Yıkama-Servisi" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#Gülüm-Halı-Yıkama-Servisi" data-interval="1000" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#Gülüm-Halı-Yıkama-Servisi" data-interval="1000" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#Gülüm-Halı-Yıkama-Servisi" data-interval="1000" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#Gülüm-Halı-Yıkama-Servisi" data-interval="1000" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="/static/images/1.jpg" alt="1" class = "img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3 class="bg-primary">Halılarınız bizimle güvende.</h3>
                <p>Profesyonel bir şekilde halılarınızın bakımı ve güvenliği Gülüm Halı Yıkama Servisi güvencesiyle gerçekten mümkün! Bu fırsattan yararlanabilmek için hemen size yakın bayiliğimizi arayabilirsiniz.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="/static/images/2.jpg" alt="2" class = "img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3 class="bg-primary">Hem ucuz, Hem kaliteli!</h3>
                <p>Kalite ararken cüzdanınız boşalması, ucuzluk ararken halılarınızın yıpranması derdiniz bitti! Kaliteyi ve ucuzluğu sizler için birleştirdik. </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="/static/images/3.jpg" alt="3" class = "img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3 class="bg-primary">Yüzleri güldüren komfor.</h3>
                <p>Verdiğimiz kaliteli hizmetin en önemli amacı, müşteri memnuniyetidir.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="/static/images/4.jpg" alt="4" class = "img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3 class="bg-primary">Tam Zamanında!</h3>
                <p>Teslimat süresi müşteri ile anlaşılan zamanda gerçekleştirilmesi garantisiyle...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Gülüm-Halı-Yıkama-Servisi" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Önceki</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Gülüm-Halı-Yıkama-Servisi" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Sonraki</span>
          </a>


        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "container">

        <div class = "row">

            <div class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <h4>Hizmet verdiğimiz alanlar</h4>
                <p>Şuanda Başakşehir ve Esenyurt olmak üzere iki bayiliğimiz bulunmakta. Bu bayilikler aracılığıyla çok geniş bir çevreye hizmetlerimizi sunuyoruz. Kendi bölgenizin de bu bayilikler kapsamında olup olmadığını görmek için Bölgeleri Göster butonuna tıklayınız.</p>
                <a class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-target = "#DENEME" role = "button" data-toggle = "modal">Bölgeleri Göster</a>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <h4>Hizmet verdiğimiz alanlar</h4>
                <p>Şuanda Başakşehir ve Esenyurt olmak üzere iki bayiliğimiz bulunmakta. Bu bayilikler aracılığıyla çok geniş bir çevreye hizmetlerimizi sunuyoruz. Kendi bölgenizin de bu bayilikler kapsamında olup olmadığını görmek için Bölgeleri Göster butonuna tıklayınız.</p>
                <a class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-target = "#DENEME1" role = "button" data-toggle = "modal">Example</a>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <h4>Hizmet verdiğimiz alanlar</h4>
                <p>Şuanda Başakşehir ve Esenyurt olmak üzere iki bayiliğimiz bulunmakta. Bu bayilikler aracılığıyla çok geniş bir çevreye hizmetlerimizi sunuyoruz. Kendi bölgenizin de bu bayilikler kapsamında olup olmadığını görmek için Bölgeleri Göster butonuna tıklayınız.</p>
                <a class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-target = "#DENEME2" role = "button" data-toggle = "modal">Example</a>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <h4>Hizmet verdiğimiz alanlar</h4>
                <p>Şuanda Başakşehir ve Esenyurt olmak üzere iki bayiliğimiz bulunmakta. Bu bayilikler aracılığıyla çok geniş bir çevreye hizmetlerimizi sunuyoruz. Kendi bölgenizin de bu bayilikler kapsamında olup olmadığını görmek için Bölgeleri Göster butonuna tıklayınız.</p>
                <a class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-target = "#DENEME3" role = "button" data-toggle = "modal">Example</a>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Gülüm Halıyıkama</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Halı Yıkama Servisi">
    <meta name="keywords" content="ucuz halıyıkama,başakşehir,halıyıkama,esenyurt,kaliteli halıyıkama">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">

</head>

<body class="body" style="background-color:#f6f6f6">

<div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home"> <img alt="Brand" src= "/static/images/logo.jpg"</a><a class="navbar-brand" href="home">Gülüm Halı®</a>

    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="home">Anasayfa <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bayiler</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vizyonumuz</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Misyonumuz</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        </li>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="first/iletisim.html">İletişim</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Daha Fazla<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Anasayfa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bayiler</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vizyonumuz</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Misyonumuz</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</div>

    <div>
       {% block content %}
       {% endblock %}   
    </div>


<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class = "navbar-inner">
        <div class = "container footer-margin-top">

            <p class="muted pull-right" ><ins>Haydar Öztürk tarafından Bootsrap ile oluşturuldu.</ins></p>
            <p class="muted pull-left" >Bütün hakları saklıdır. 2016</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="DENEME" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal0">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="modal0">Bayilere göre bölgeler</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Başahşehir</h3>
            <p> Başakşehir şubemiz, Başakşehir,Kayaşehir,Altınşehir,Şahintepe,Tahtakale,Bahçeşehir ve Esenkent'in bütün mahallelerini,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
          <h3>Esenyurt</h3>
            <p> Esenyurt şubemiz, Beylikdüzü,Esenyurt ve Avcılar ilçelerinin bütün mahalle,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="DENEME1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="modal1">Bayilere göre bölgeler</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Başahşehir</h3>
            <p> Başakşehir şubemiz, Başakşehir,Kayaşehir,Altınşehir,Şahintepe,Tahtakale,Bahçeşehir ve Esenkent'in bütün mahallelerini,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
          <h3>Esenyurt</h3>
            <p> Esenyurt şubemiz, Beylikdüzü,Esenyurt ve Avcılar ilçelerinin bütün mahalle,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="DENEME2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="modal2">Bayilere göre bölgeler</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Başahşehir</h3>
            <p> Başakşehir şubemiz, Başakşehir,Kayaşehir,Altınşehir,Şahintepe,Tahtakale,Bahçeşehir ve Esenkent'in bütün mahallelerini,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
          <h3>Esenyurt</h3>
            <p> Esenyurt şubemiz, Beylikdüzü,Esenyurt ve Avcılar ilçelerinin bütün mahalle,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="DENEME3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal3">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="modal3">Bayilere göre bölgeler</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Başahşehir</h3>
            <p> Başakşehir şubemiz, Başakşehir,Kayaşehir,Altınşehir,Şahintepe,Tahtakale,Bahçeşehir ve Esenkent'in bütün mahallelerini,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
          <h3>Esenyurt</h3>
            <p> Esenyurt şubemiz, Beylikdüzü,Esenyurt ve Avcılar ilçelerinin bütün mahalle,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I thought `<a href="{% url name_of_register_url %}>Register</a>` This solution could solve my problem but it didn't. mybe partly did. after I implant this solution to my  header.html file it become like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Gülüm Halıyıkama</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Halı Yıkama Servisi">
    <meta name="keywords" content="ucuz halıyıkama,başakşehir,halıyıkama,esenyurt,kaliteli halıyıkama">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">

</head>

<body class="body" style="background-color:#f6f6f6">

<div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url home.html %}"> <img alt="Brand" src= "/static/images/logo.jpg"</a><a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url home.html %}">Gülüm Halı®</a>

    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="{% url home.html %}">Anasayfa <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bayiler</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vizyonumuz</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Misyonumuz</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        </li>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="{% url iletisim.html %}">İletişim</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Daha Fazla<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Anasayfa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bayiler</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vizyonumuz</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Misyonumuz</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</div>

    <div>
       {% block content %}
       {% endblock %}   
    </div>


<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class = "navbar-inner">
        <div class = "container footer-margin-top">

            <p class="muted pull-right" ><ins>Haydar Öztürk tarafından Bootsrap ile oluşturuldu.</ins></p>
            <p class="muted pull-left" >Bütün hakları saklıdır. 2016</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="DENEME" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal0">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="modal0">Bayilere göre bölgeler</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Başahşehir</h3>
            <p> Başakşehir şubemiz, Başakşehir,Kayaşehir,Altınşehir,Şahintepe,Tahtakale,Bahçeşehir ve Esenkent'in bütün mahallelerini,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
          <h3>Esenyurt</h3>
            <p> Esenyurt şubemiz, Beylikdüzü,Esenyurt ve Avcılar ilçelerinin bütün mahalle,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="DENEME1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="modal1">Bayilere göre bölgeler</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Başahşehir</h3>
            <p> Başakşehir şubemiz, Başakşehir,Kayaşehir,Altınşehir,Şahintepe,Tahtakale,Bahçeşehir ve Esenkent'in bütün mahallelerini,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
          <h3>Esenyurt</h3>
            <p> Esenyurt şubemiz, Beylikdüzü,Esenyurt ve Avcılar ilçelerinin bütün mahalle,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="DENEME2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="modal2">Bayilere göre bölgeler</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Başahşehir</h3>
            <p> Başakşehir şubemiz, Başakşehir,Kayaşehir,Altınşehir,Şahintepe,Tahtakale,Bahçeşehir ve Esenkent'in bütün mahallelerini,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
          <h3>Esenyurt</h3>
            <p> Esenyurt şubemiz, Beylikdüzü,Esenyurt ve Avcılar ilçelerinin bütün mahalle,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="DENEME3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal3">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="modal3">Bayilere göre bölgeler</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Başahşehir</h3>
            <p> Başakşehir şubemiz, Başakşehir,Kayaşehir,Altınşehir,Şahintepe,Tahtakale,Bahçeşehir ve Esenkent'in bütün mahallelerini,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
          <h3>Esenyurt</h3>
            <p> Esenyurt şubemiz, Beylikdüzü,Esenyurt ve Avcılar ilçelerinin bütün mahalle,cadde ve sokaklarını kapsamaktadır. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

After this change it gave this error.

[error looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNFzj.jpg)

This is the text in this picture;

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 508
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/haydar/haliyikama',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Sat, 7 May 2016 11:15:09 +0000
```

And this is the line it gives error says debug tool

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix
            lookup_view_s = "%s.%s" % (m, n)
        else:
            lookup_view_s = lookup_view
        patterns = [pattern for (possibility, pattern, defaults) in possibilities]
        raise NoReverseMatch("Reverse for '%s' with arguments '%s' and keyword "
                "arguments '%s' not found. %d pattern(s) tried: %s" %
                             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)) ...
class LocaleRegexURLResolver(RegexURLResolver):
    """
    A URL resolver that always matches the active language code as URL prefix.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your setup; but nothing that's major:

1. Your file is called `haliyikama/first/url.py`; but you are including it as `url(r'^', include('first.urls')),` (note the `urls`); you need to change the name of your file to `haliyikama/first/urls.py`.
2. Your patterns are also incorrect. Your pattern needs to be `^$` for the very first pattern in your url list.
3. The reason `admin` is not working, is because you haven't mapped it to any url pattern; try adding `url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),` to your main `urls.py`.
4. `href="{% url home.html %}"` this is not how you use the `url` tag, you need to pass it the name of the *view*, not the template; like this `href="{% url 'home' %}"`.

I also suggest you read a quick primer on regular expressions because these are important when defining urls; as they work on the concept of pattern matching.

Here are some quick tips:

Lets say you have a pattern like this `url(r'^home/')`

This means any url that starts with `home/`, so it will match `home/foo/bar/zoo/hello` along with anything else `home/hello.html` etc. This is why usually when you have an "open ended" pattern like this, you usually include a lot of other urls after it, like this `url(r'^home/', include('home.urls'))`.

Now, when you do `url(r'^home/', include('home.urls'))` this means *"any url that starts with home/, match it against the list of urls found in home/urls.py file"*.

Lets say in our `home/urls.py` file, we have:

```
url(r'^$', views.index),
```

This `^$` means a *blank string*, so `views.index` will be called when the url is `http://localhost:8080/home/`

Here is another example:

```
url(r'^members/$', views.members),`
```

Now this will match `home/members/`.

Hopefully this helps clarify the issues you are facing. Please have a read through the tutorial which covers these concepts.

Comment: I am very thankful for your help. I did step 2,3,4 but 1 was just a typing mistake in this website so it's urls instead of url.py. After I did those steps I still get the last error I get and its NoReverseMatch error.

it says error during template rendering

In template /home/haydar/haliyikama/first/templates/first/home.html, error at line 30

in like 30 there is a paragraph so I did not understand. 

I will defenatly watch more tutorials after I finish this project thank you very much again

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I had was using the URL tags. If you had some problem like this and pop-up in here, here is the answer how I solve my problem with the help I get from Burhan Khalid;

Yes my url tag was wrong but instead of href="{% url home %}" doing something like that I should have do something like href="{% url 'home' %}"
there is not much difference but it will help to call the name so it can send you that link. The Url tags in the HTML file was wrong.